# How can I categorize text according to html tags from extracted text from website source code

Tags: python, text

Is there a way to categorize the text extracted from a HTML source code and place each word under the HTML tags that are categorized

Eg - H1 - My First Heading
The element defines a large heading

```
 p  - My first paragraph.
```

Like wise categorizing all text according to the HTML tags and meta tags.

```html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Comment
import urllib.request


def tag_visible(element):
    if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', 'head', 'title', 'meta', '[document]']:
        return False
    if isinstance(element, Comment):
        return False
    return True


def text_from_html(body):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'html.parser')
    texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
    visible_texts = filter(tag_visible, texts)  
    return u" ".join(t.strip() for t in visible_texts)

html = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp').read()
print(text_from_html(html))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you had a look at BeautifulSoup library?

Comment: I have added my code using  BeautifulSoup library. It extracts all the text within the HTML source code

Comment: I believe `soup.find_all` already does that. `soup.find_all('p')` would return all the `<p>` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call texts = soup.findAll(text=True), you get an array of elements.
Each one of those elements has the name property, so you can get the tag of the element.

```
return u" ".join(t.name, t.strip() for t in visible_texts)
```